# Best linux filesystem filter option?

Tags: linux, api, filter, filesystems, driver

I need a linux filesystem filter with which to enforce ACL policy on filesystem calls dynamically (allow/deny read/writes based on stuff computed at runtime).

So far I have stumbled onto [DazukoFS](http://dazuko.dnsalias.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) and [Related Work](http://dazuko.dnsalias.org/wiki/index.php/Related_Work).
What I dont like about DazukoFS is that it has to be compiled for each kernel release.

1. Is there some user-mode library that can filter filesystem calls dynamically?
2. If not, is there some kernel-mode library that can filter FS calls dynamically, and not compile it for each kernel release?
3. If not, what is the best choice among [DazukoFS](http://dazuko.dnsalias.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) and [others](http://dazuko.dnsalias.org/wiki/index.php/Related_Work) ?

Comment: Looking at DazukoFS, I can only advise to check FUSE too -  http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=FileSystems - and probably ask that on the fuse-devel mail list.

Comment: Why are there so many trolls downvoting with no comment?

Comment: One isn't many, a lot of people don't like it when you answer your own question (which is just plain silly if you ask me).

Comment: I answered because other people might find it useful, if they come here form google. (1) It is the answer to the question that no one else provided, redirfs does all 3 points, and (2) no one gave me a better answer. One is many (judging from my other questions)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have chosen [RedirFS](http://www.redirfs.org) Redirecting Filesystem Framework.

- similar to windows minifilter drivers in many ways
- simple enough and featurefull
- has examples of programs
- nice docs (but scattered)

Comment: Looks like this is not being maintained anymore.

Answer (score 2):

If fanotify ever gets into the kernel, it would provide precisely what you're asking for.

But unfortunately it hasn't got in yet.

EDIT:

fanotify has been merged into 2.6.36.

Pull request was:
http://lkml.org/lkml/2010/8/6/273

Comment: Can you provide a canonical link to this project, and its proposals to be merged?